# How to install a .dsc file on linux

Tags: linux, debian

I have to install manually a file with a type I never seen before: `.dsc`

How can I install this kind of file on linux??

Comment: That's not a software package, it's just a text file that describes a software package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [FilExt.com](http://filext.com/file-extension/dsc):

> Debian (Source Control (Source Package))   Typically lower case on
>   *nix systems. Description File DPKG-source
>
> Debian source packages consist of two or three files. First the *.DSC
>   file which contains some information information about the package and
>   checksums for the remaining file(s). Second a *.TAR.GZ holding the
>   upstream sources. And third, if any changes need to be made to the
>   sources, they are distributed as *.DIFF.GZ. To simplify the unpacking
>   process a single command, "dpkg-source -x *.dsc", is provided by
>   Debian to unpack these files. This association is classified as Source
>   Code.

Answer (score 9):

From [Linuxquestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-install-dsc-file-in-linux-896928/)

Full procedure to install the package related to a `.dsc` file:

0. Before you begin, note that, besides the `.dsc` file, you must have the corresponding `xxx-orig.tar.xz` and `xxx-debian.tar.xz` files.
1. Install `dpkg-dev` package, if not present in your linux machine

   `sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev`
2. Following command extracts the package into an automatically created directory. Note: the necessary `xxx-orig.tar.xz` and `xxx-debian.tar.xz` files must be in the same directory as the `.dsc` file in order to work properly.

   `dpkg-source -x yourfile.dsc`

   If you get error message concerning the signature, [check this post here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56841/gpg-cant-check-signature#198420).
3. To build the package get into the directory that was created in 2nd step and issue this command

   `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b`
4. To install the built package issue this command

   `dpkg -i ../yourfile_arch.deb`